# Eigen c++ : area hyperbolic tangent (atanh) of a complex matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to compute the area hyperbolic tangent (atanh) of my Eigen complex matrix.
I didn't find in the "Eigen library" a function that to compute the atanh, can I use this expression for my matrix:

`atanh(x)= 1/2 (ln (1+x)-ln (1-x))`

Thank you :)

Comment: Mmm nope, better use [std::atanh](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/atanh) with [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to distinguish between taking the atanh of a matrix, and the atanh of its entries. If it's just the `atanh` of its entries then you can do what @Ptaq666 suggests. If it is the`atanh` of the matrix, then this is defined by performing an eigen decomposition to find `E` (the matrix of eigenvectors) and `l` (the eigenvalues). The arctanh of the matrix is then  defined as `E * diag(atanh(l)) * E^-1`.

This is what `Eigen::MatrixBase::log`, `Eigen::MatrixBase::sin`, etc do so you should check out their implementations.

(Equivalently you can replace `1` by the identity matrix in your expression)

Comment: my matrix is already diagonal
I think  the atanh of the matrix is equal to the atanh of its entries
isn't it?

Comment: If it's a diagonal matrix then yes, you can use `std::atanh` like @Ptaq666` suggests on the diagonal elements.

Comment: The coeff-wise atanh is readily available in the head of Eigen: `mat.array().atanh()` or `atanh(mat.array())`.

Comment: Eigen Library does not contain the arc hyperbolic fonctions : https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html

Comment: @ggael , i tried your expression, but i had this error :  'class Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, 3, 3> >' has no member named 'atanh'|

Comment: my bad, we only have a scalar-wise wrapper to `atanh`, I did not read carefully enough the output of my search for atanh.